# Passing data from View to Controller in ajax ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get values from table which contains checkboxes and one column named "propertyname", I need to loop on table and get value "true" from checked and "false" from unchecked and value of column "propertyname". and then pass all this data in array from view to controller via ajax.

I am stuck - please help

Kindly see the screenshot: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1d5iDaf2zqfrpRLkdUE9sIqBj7duoGpZJ

Comment: Friendly reminder: Please provide code example which comply with [mcve] to help us reproduce your issue and propose a solution. Without any examples currently we can only guess what things went wrong.

Comment: Please add your model class here or your database table

Comment: public class ListToUpdate
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }

        public bool IsReadable { get; set; }

        public bool IsWriteable { get; set; }
        public bool IsRequired { get; set; }

    }